# What does “Average Width” mean in crystallography?

Tags: crystal-structure, crystallography

Mathematician G. Polya noted (the solution for Problem 8, Axes of a Cube) in his book *How to Solve it*:

> ... there are three kinds of axes:
>
> (1) 4 axes, each through two opposite vertices ...
>
> (2) 6 axes, each through the mid-points of two opposite edges ...
>
> (3) 3 axes, each through the center of two opposite faces ...
>
> ... The desired average is
>
> $$\frac{4\sqrt{3}+6\sqrt{2}+3}{13}=1.416$$
>
> (This problem may be useful in preparing the reader for the study of crystallography. For the reader sufficiently advanced in the integral calculus it may be observed that the average computed is a fairly good approximation to the “average width” of the cube, which is, in fact, 3/2=1.5)

However, I calculated the "average width" of 1.22 to 1.24 in math meaning, which is far different from 1.5. See my post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4207524

Is there really such a concept in crystallography?